# How to display not synched yet firebase messages in recyclerview when is user offline?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app using firebase realtime database, the problem that I am facing is when the user is offline and they send a message, it appears automatically in recyclerview for android version larger than 4.2.2 and version 4.2.2 and below it doesn't show offline messages, I want to do the same thing in these lower versions, how to display offline messages(not synched) in recyclerview?
This is the fetchMessages method:

```
private void fetchMessages() {
        if(mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        Messages messages = snapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        messagesList.add(messages);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messagesList.size()-1);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            };
            messagesRef.child(pair).addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Display msg offline used below code in your application class like below

```
public class APP NAME extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
       
    }
}
```

**And Change your manifest as**

```
<application
    android:name=".APP NAME"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer , i know how to display offline messages but in this question what i am asking for that when offline user send a message it is cached until the user get internet connection , i want to display this cached message(not synched yet) in recyclerview and this work automatically in android version larger than 4.2.2  so i want to do the same thing for version 4.2.2 and lower

Comment: @Hamdy okey misunderstanding  you want display msg from cached

Comment: yes , msg that cached for synching to realtime databse until user has internet connection